# how to upload at new name and section

Tags: php, arrays, upload

**I have a problem that made me lose my temper really I have the following code
OK ?**

```
$sections = array("Other","Romance","Horror","Sucid","Dance","Comedy");

$vedioname = $_POST['vedionamet'];

$path = $_POST['selectsection'];

$finalpath =realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/Uploads/".$path);

$vedname= $_FILES['vedio']['name'];

$temp=$_FILES['vedio']['tmp_name'];

$type = $_FILES["vedio"]['type'];

$size = $_FILES['vedio']['size'];

$errors = $_FILES['vedio']['error'];

if($_POST['uploadsub']){

move_uploaded_file($temp,$finalpath.$vedioname);

echo "Done Uploaded".$type;

}else
{
 echo "$error";
}
```

**The first problem is supposed to be the process of uploading the file to file uploads
The file is not even uploaded to the same file as the page
Second, the goal is to write the name of the file uploaded within the text, but what is happening in reverse exactly that
So how to make the upload process successful
Inside the uploads / value received from the form section
And the new name of the received value of the form**

```
    <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="inputs">
    <label class="labels" for="name">Vedio Name: </label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="vedionamet" value="vedio"> </br> 
        <label class="labels" for="selectsection">Select Section :</label>
        <select name="selectsection" id="section" >

            <?php 
            foreach($sections as $pathat){
                echo "<option value='$pathat'>" . "$pathat" . "</option>";

            };
            ?>
        </select></br>
        <label class="labels" for="upup">Select Vedio : </label>
        <input id="upload" type="file" name="vedio"></br>
        <input id="subb" type="submit" name="uploadsub" value="Upload">
        </
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the HTML part, you may change the action to "#" if you want to use a same page to handle the upload request.

For the PHP part, you may try the following codes, it works on my computer. Please also make sure that you have already established these **sub video folders** in `Uploads` folder

```
<?php
$sections = array("Other","Romance","Horror","Sucid","Dance","Comedy");
//add one condition to avoid warning when the page first loads
if(isset($_POST["selectsection"])){

    $vedioname = $_POST['vedionamet'];

    $path = $_POST['selectsection'];

    //Use this to get the path
    $finalpath = realpath(dirname(getcwd())) . '\\Uploads\\' . $path. '\\';

    $vedname= $_FILES['vedio']['name'];

    $temp=$_FILES['vedio']['tmp_name'];

    //Use this to get the extension of file name
    $type = pathinfo($vedname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $size = $_FILES['vedio']['size'];

    $errors = $_FILES['vedio']['error'];

    if($_POST['uploadsub']){

    move_uploaded_file($temp,$finalpath.$vedioname.".".$type);

    echo "Done Uploaded".$type;

    }else
    {
    echo "$error";
    }
}

?>
```